# cxjs What is the best way to build a cxjs widget from a jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, cxjs

I would like to migrate an older jquery app that uses jquery d3 charts. what is the best way to wrap jquery $ components in cxjs widgets?

I wasn't able to adapt https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html and found no other option yet..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.. helped myself this time :-)

load jquery and dependencies in the html file and see above react integration example.

To get the react VDOM into cx you need to import:

```
import React from 'react';
import { VDOM } from "cx-react";
import { findDOMNode } from "react-dom";
```

Comment: VDOM is an alias for React (or Preact) in CxJS. You can import it from `cx/ui`.